# Error Creating MySQL table using Python

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7

I am busy trying to create a MySQL table using python to no avail. I am connected to MySQL and I have created the database but keep getting the following error message:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EOD_Date DATE,
Symbol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Holding' at line 3
```

I have looked through the create table syntax documentation and I can't work out what the issue is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Here is my code to create the table:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE prices
(
Index INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EOD_Date DATE,
Symbol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Holdings_Q INT NOT NULL,
EOD_Price FLOAT(,2) NOT NULL,
OIL_Price FLOAT(,2) NOT NULL,
Account_Number INT NOT NULL,
Account_Type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Asset_Class VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Security_Desc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Security_Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Holdings_Val FLOAT(,2), NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (Index))ENGINE=InnoDB""")
```

Any suggestions or input would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`Index` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. If you have to use that as field name, you can escape it with tick like:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE prices
(
`Index` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EOD_Date DATE,
Symbol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Holdings_Q INT NOT NULL,
EOD_Price FLOAT(,2) NOT NULL,
OIL_Price FLOAT(,2) NOT NULL,
Account_Number INT NOT NULL,
Account_Type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Asset_Class VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Security_Desc VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Security_Type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Holdings_Val FLOAT(,2), NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`Index`))ENGINE=InnoDB""")
```

Comment: Thanks @fabricator I updated the code to include 'Index' where necessary however I am still getting the exact same error message

Comment: I have managed to answer my question, I will post code when I am able to

Comment: @da4l it's not 'single-quotes', it's \`backticks\`.